# Any way to store and work on logical expressions in python

Tags: python, logic, logical-operators

I want to store and work (access each literal from an expression and further) on logical expressions like ((A /\ B) / C) in python. Can anyone please suggest a data structure or a way to do it using classes. I am new to python so please explain your answer in detail.

Comment: Do a search for "Python logic programming" and check out some of the results.

Answer (score -1):

There is a lib named sympy. Maybe you can have a try

```
from sympy import *
a,b,c = symbols('a b c')
(a & b) | c
Or(And(a, b), c)
```